# A function that returns different column values based on input

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Here is a table **FRUITS** -

```
FILTER  A   B   C
Apple   0   3   6
Orange  1   4   7
Apricot 2   5   8
```

Is it possible to create a function that returns column A for apple (0), B for Orange(4) and C for Apricot(8)?

```
SELECT Fruit_Function('Apple') FROM dual; --RESULT 0.
SELECT Fruit_Function('Orange') FROM dual; --RESULT 4.
SELECT Fruit_Function('Apricot') FROM dual; --RESULT 8.
```

Right now I have a function like this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Fruit_Function (v_id integer, v_filter varchar2)
RETURN varchar2 as

    v_rp varchar2(500);

BEGIN
    SELECT ASSIGNEE INTO v_rp
    FROM FRUITS a
    WHERE a.id = v_id AND a.filter = v_filter;

    RETURN v_rp;
END Fruit_Function;
```

This function returns the column name, but not the actual value.

Comment: How about just using a `case` expression instead?

Comment: The idea is to remove complex logic from the query. The case statement would be used 100+ times in a package. So if we could simplify it, that would be ideal.

Comment: I don't understand the logic. Why is it column A for 'Apple'? Why is it column B for 'Orange'? What would be returned for 'Peach' if fruits contained an additional row for filter='Peach', A=1, B=2, C=3? Would it be different for filter='Peach', A=3, B=2, C=1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a view!

```
create view v_t as
    select t.*,
           (case when filter = 'Apple' then a
                 when filter = 'Orange' then b
                 when filter = 'Apricot' then C 
           end) as result
    from t;
```

Then, use the view for the queries in your package.

You can also add the column as a computed column directly into the table:

```
alter table t add result number generated always as
           (case when filter = 'Apple' then a
                 when filter = 'Orange' then b
                 when filter = 'Apricot' then C 
            end);
```

With this approach, the column looks like it is part of the table.

Comment: This is interesting, let me spend some time with this approach, thanks!

Comment: If all the `case` conditions are equality tests, then the alternative syntax `case filter when ...` is less verbose. Also, you don't need brackets around the `case` expression in your first example (or around any SELECT list expression).

Comment: @WilliamRobertson . . . I use parentheses as a visual tool to separate the `case` expression from other expressions.  Whenever I use the simple `case`, it seems that I always end up consolidating conditions using `in` or adding an inequality condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `case` expression

```
SELECT
    CASE filter WHEN 'Apple' THEN A WHEN 'Orange' THEN B WHEN 'Apricot' THEN C END AS result
FROM
    myTable
```

If you want to reuse it 100+ times, create a view from it and output all the other columns as well

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW myTableEx
   SELECT
      CASE filter WHEN 'Apple' THEN A WHEN 'Orange' THEN B WHEN 'Apricot' THEN C END AS result,
      filter, A, B, C, ...
   FROM
      myTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below logic in function

```
Function(input)
Begin
If(input =='Apple')
Select A from table name
Else if(input =='something')
Select B from table name
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a function that takes 2 input parameters called filter_value, col_value

For the function definition,

1. Define a variable called v_result
2. Select
3. Execute immediate ‘ select ‘ || col_value  || ‘ from your_table where filter=‘’’ || filter_value || ‘’’’ into v_result;
4. Return v result;